# Using wet saw for cutting tile

Tags: tile

How long does the tile have to dry before I can put it on the wall ?
Should I dry it with a heat gun or is drying it with a towel good .

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How are you adhering the tile to the wall? (Edit the answer into your question.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using thin-set, then damp is fine (as in, dry with a towel).  It is usually a good idea to damp the tile and substrate with a sponge anyway, (especially if tiling to wood/gypsum(drywall) etc.) so that the substrate doesn't soak up all the moisture from the thin-set.

If using mastic, you want the tiles to be dry.